# unable to export from powershell to CSV

Tags: powershell

Pls help a poor newby over here...below is my script with the errors at the bottom of the script. The main issue is that i am unable to export to CSV

```
PS C:\Users\LUPUWANA> $logs = get-eventlog system -ComputerName cafeserver -source Microsoft-Windows-Winlogon -After (Get-Date).AddDays(-7);
$res = @(); ForEach ($log in $logs) {if($log.instanceid -eq 7001) {$type = "Logon"} Elseif ($log.instanceid -eq 7002){$type="Logoff"} Else {Continue} $res += New-Object PSObject -Property @{Time = $log.TimeWritten; "Event" = $type; User = (New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier $Log.ReplacementStrings[1]).Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])}};
Export-Csv -Path C:\users\lupuwana\desktop\events.csv
```

oss get-help -detailed

```
Supply values for the following parameters:
InputObject: 
oss : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Width'. Cannot convert value "get-help" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a 
correct format."
At line:4 char:5
+ oss get-help -detailed
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [oss], ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,oss
```

Comment: As for `oss get-help -detailed`: It's unclear what you're trying to do; if you want help for `oss`, use `get-help oss -detailed`. If you want to send output from `get-help -detailed` to `oss`, use `get-help -detailed | oss`, though the use of `oss` (a function wrapper for `Out-String -Stream`) would have no effect in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop builds an object called `$res`, so assuming that's the object you wish to export to CSV, you need to supply that object to the `Export-Csv` Cmdlet:

```
Export-Csv -InputObject $res -Path C:\users\lupuwana\desktop\events.csv
```

You may also wish to add the `-NoTypeInformation` option too otherwise your file will contain an extra header row describing the object type.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, much appreciated however my worry now is; on powershell i get proper results, see below... but when converted to csv, there template is blank

Comment: Count,"Length","LongLength","Rank","SyncRoot","IsReadOnly","IsFixedSize","IsSynchronized"
13,"13","13","1","System.Object[]","False","True","False"